# How to show three oldest people

Tags: sql

I have this table:

[image: table]

Task: show first name, last name and age of the three oldest employees.

I know that i can show the oldest employer using

```
WHERE birth_date=(SELECT MIN(birth_date);
```

but how show 3 oldest employees?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using. Hint: `ORDER BY` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: ^ and `top` or `limit` depending on the DB engine

Comment: `FETCH FIRST` is the ANSI SQL way, supported by many products nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Use of SQL **TOP** and followed by number of result needed a numeric value
Inclusion of **ORDER BY** to provide the context of result set:

- For oldest order `ASC` for Youngest order `DESC`

```
SELECT TOP 3
    first_name , last_name
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY 
    birth_date;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but with standard SQL you would use window functions:

```
select first_name, last_name, current_date - birth_date as age
from ( 
  select first_name, last_name, birth_date,
         dense_rank() over (order by birth_date) as rnk
  from employees
) t
where rnk <= 3;
```

While window functions (`dense_rank() over (...)`) are pretty common 
in modern databases, not all support subtracting two date values like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name, current_date - birth_date as age from employees ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 3;
```

If you're picky about the day level difference:

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name, julianday('now') - julianday(birth_date) as age_in_days from employees ORDER BY age_in_days DESC LIMIT 3;
```